# Prestashop free shipping on first purchase

Tags: prestashop

In Prestashop, how can I provide free shipping on first time purchase for every customer? Either check from database whether customer exist? Or send every new registered customer a voucher code to waive shipping charges?
How to code either way?

Answer (score 1):

Simple SQL-Statement with ps_orders:

```
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id_customer) FROM ps_orders WHERE id_customer = %d",$id_customer)
```

Execute this String and check if $res == 0, then offer "free shipping" else "normal shipping".